# iOS Everyplay integration: Calling "showEveryplay" leads to a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, everyplay

We use Everyplay in our game for recording and it seemed to work properly, but e.g., when calling the following line our app crashes:

`[[EveryplaysharedInstance] showEveryplay]`

Testing on iOS 9.1, iPhone 5S. The crash happens no matter if we call it ourselves in our UI or by pressing the Everyplay button in the preview window of Everyplay (shown when calling `[[EveryplaysharedInstance] playLastRecording]`). There is another crash when simply closing Everyplay's preview window.

- All frameworks are added.
- Initialization is done in the method `viewDidLoad` of our view controller:

  [EveryplayinitWithDelegate:self andParentViewController:self]
- EveryplayDelegate methods are being called as expected. Just before the crash `everyplayShown` delegate method is called.

Did you experience similar problems? Any idea where to search?

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Added stack trace and crash log!

Stack trace (bt output in the console):

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1faed, 0x00000001993bf140 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
frame #0: 0x00000001993bf140 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
frame #1: 0x0000000199488ef8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
frame #2: 0x0000000199332b78 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 140
frame #3: 0x00000001012f9490 Project`uncaught_exception_handler + 36
frame #4: 0x0000000183f912d0 CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 652
frame #5: 0x0000000198a5423c libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 112
frame #6: 0x00000001980f6f44 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
frame #7: 0x00000001980f685c libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 136
frame #8: 0x0000000198a54094 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 332
frame #9: 0x0000000188d6b8bc QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 164
frame #10: 0x0000000188d6b6f4 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 424
frame #11: 0x000000018522a2f8 IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
frame #12: 0x0000000183f32840 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 180
frame #13: 0x0000000183f48c7c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
frame #14: 0x0000000183f483b4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
frame #15: 0x0000000183f4610c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1800
frame #16: 0x0000000183e74ca0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
frame #17: 0x000000018f0b0088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
frame #18: 0x000000018958cffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
frame #19: 0x000000010102d568 Project`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdfba80) + 152 at main.m:39
frame #20: 0x00000001992a28b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Crash log from XCode:

```
    Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x183c58f48 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19871bf80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x183c58e90 +[NSException raise:format:] + 120
3   UIKit                           0x18926456c -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 912
4   UIKit                           0x189263efc -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenStatusBarAndDeviceAndOrientation:] + 96
5   UIKit                           0x18956e9e8 -[UIViewController _legacyInterfaceOrientation] + 652
6   Project                         0x10146cc30 -[EveryplayNavigationViewController loadView] + 88
7   UIKit                           0x1891ebd44 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 144
8   UIKit                           0x1891ebc9c -[UIViewController view] + 28
9   Project                         0x10146c850 -[EveryplayNavigationViewController initWithOverlayNavigationBar:] + 164
10  Project                         0x101489f50 -[EveryplaySocialViewController initWithOverlayNavigationBar:] + 56
11  Project                         0x101424330 __34-[Everyplay showEveryplayWithURL:]_block_invoke + 432
12  Project                         0x10144ec54 +[EveryplayCommon runInMainThread:] + 64
13  Project                         0x101424154 -[Everyplay showEveryplayWithURL:] + 136
14  Project                         0x101424090 -[Everyplay showEveryplayWithPathInternal:] + 384
15  Project                         0x101423074 -[Everyplay showEveryplayWithPath:] + 192
16  Project                         0x101422f98 -[Everyplay showEveryplay] + 108
17  Project                         0x100268700 -[GameViewController notificationHandler:] (GameViewController.mm:577)
```

Well after seeing the above crash log it had something to do with the handling of the device orientation in connection with Everyplay. Our game is played in landscape only, so I thought that portrait orientations are required, too. Adding also the two portrait orientations in the .plist did fix the problem. Everyplay's view controller seems to need the definition as such.

Not sure if problems can occur for other iOS versions, other devices. It feels like a hack. What do you think?

Comment: What does the crash say is the reason?  What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: I have provided now much more information in the post.